# how to avoid installing electron as a dependency when I don't need it?

Tags: javascript, electron

I recently opened a [pull request](https://github.com/doocs/md/pull/64) in a [repository](https://github.com/doocs/md) (designed to render markdown into beautified html), merging `electron` into it. But the author says when he runs `npm install`, the installation of electron appears to take a massive amount of time. As you could perhaps see from the pull request and repository, we are Chinese, and the Chinese government has some very strict rules on web browsing, and has blocked a bunch of websites including google, stackoverflow, etc. GitHub & npm sources are also very slow here, so this might be the problem.

However, considering most of the users are Chine sehe asked me whether there is a way to avoid installing `electron` when a user cloned his code locally and tries to run the webapp version locally, without requiring `electron`.

Perhaps adding `electron` into `devDependencies`? I do not know... anyway this is our `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "md",
  "version": "1.5.1",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node manifest.js & npm run dev:h5",
    "build": "node manifest.js & npm run build:h5",
    "build:h5-netlify": "cross-env SERVER_ENV=NETLIFY node manifest.js & npm run build:h5",
    "build:h5-electron": "cross-env SERVER_ENV=ELECTRON node manifest.js & npm run electron:build",
    "build:app-plus": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:custom": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production uniapp-cli custom",
    "build:h5": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_OUTPUT_DIR=dist UNI_PLATFORM=h5 vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-360": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-360 vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-alipay": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-alipay vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-baidu": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-baidu vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-kuaishou": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-kuaishou vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-qq": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-qq vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-toutiao": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-toutiao vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-weixin": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-weixin vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-native": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-native vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-webview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-webview-huawei": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-huawei vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-webview-union": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-union vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "dev:app-plus": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:custom": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development uniapp-cli custom",
    "dev:h5": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_OUTPUT_DIR=dist UNI_PLATFORM=h5 vue-cli-service uni-serve",
    "dev:mp-360": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-360 vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-alipay": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-alipay vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-baidu": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-baidu vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-kuaishou": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-kuaishou vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-qq": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-qq vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-toutiao": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-toutiao vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-weixin": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-weixin vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-native": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-native vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-webview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-webview-huawei": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-huawei vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-webview-union": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-union vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:h5-electron": "cross-env SERVER_ENV=ELECTRON node manifest.js & npm run electron:serve",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "info": "node node_modules/@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-uni/commands/info.js",
    "serve:quickapp-native": "node node_modules/@dcloudio/uni-quickapp-native/bin/serve.js",
    "test:android": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus UNI_OS_NAME=android jest -i",
    "test:h5": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=h5 jest -i",
    "test:ios": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus UNI_OS_NAME=ios jest -i",
    "test:mp-baidu": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=mp-baidu jest -i",
    "test:mp-weixin": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=mp-weixin jest -i"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dcloudio/uni-app-plus": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-h5": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-helper-json": "*",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-360": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-alipay": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-baidu": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-qq": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-toutiao": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-vue": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-weixin": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-quickapp-native": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-quickapp-webview": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-stat": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@vue/shared": "^3.0.11",
    "ali-oss": "^6.15.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "buffer-from": "^1.1.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.61.0",
    "core-js": "^3.11.0",
    "cos-js-sdk-v5": "^1.2.9",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.15.1",
    "flyio": "^0.6.14",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "juice": "^7.0.0",
    "marked": "^2.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettify": "^0.1.7",
    "qiniu-js": "^3.1.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dcloudio/types": "*",
    "@dcloudio/uni-automator": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-cli-shared": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-migration": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-template-compiler": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-hbuilderx": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-uni": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-uni-optimize": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/webpack-uni-mp-loader": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@dcloudio/webpack-uni-pages-loader": "^2.0.0-31820210406002",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.12",
    "async-validator": "^3.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^11.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^25.4.0",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "mini-types": "*",
    "miniprogram-api-typings": "*",
    "postcss-comment": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "Android >= 4",
    "ios >= 8"
  ],
  "uni-app": {
    "scripts": {}
  },
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

Comment: if you have to acheive this.. then u have to separate out the entry point. making electron not install would make the dependent code to fail.. so make different entry point and seperate out the app into two..

Comment: ah, I do see. thank you for your response. this would take some time thought, I imagine.